# How to select results in MYSQL with two combined situations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a query for the below conditions

**Given film_actor and film tables from the DVD Rental sample database find all movies both Sidney Crowe (actor_id = 105) and Salma Nolte (actor_id = 122) cast in together and order the result set alphabetically.**

```
**film schema**
 Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
title       | character varying(255)      | not null
film_id     | smallint                    | not null

**film_actor schema** 
Column     | Type                        | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+----------
actor_id    | smallint                    | not null
film_id     | smallint                    | not null
last_update | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

I'm not able to understand how to write query where result will have movie titles where both actors TOGETHER have worked.

`SELECT f.title AS title FROM film f INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id WHERE fa.actor_id IN(102, 122) ORDER BY title;`

I tried this query but didn't get the expected result, instead it is returning results **where one of the two actors were part of the movie**. However, I want the results **where both the actors have worked together and not individually**

Comment: `GROUP BY f.title HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` - This is one of many duplicate questions for witch it's hard to find a good reference.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the film ids with both actors by grouping by film_id the table film_actor and setting the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT film_id 
FROM film_actor
WHERE actor_id IN (102, 122)
GROUP BY film_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) = 2
```

Finally use this query to get the film titles:

```
SELECT title 
FROM film
WHERE film_id IN (
    SELECT film_id 
    FROM film_actor
    WHERE actor_id IN (102, 122)
    GROUP BY film_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) = 2 
)
ORDER BY title
```

Another way of getting the same result is with the use of EXISTS (twice):

```
SELECT f.title
FROM film f 
WHERE 
  EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM film_actor
    WHERE film_id = f.film_id AND actor_id = 102 
  )
  AND
  EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM film_actor
    WHERE film_id = f.film_id AND actor_id = 122 
  )
ORDER BY f.title
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of self-join. Basically, you can join the `film` table twice with the `film_actor` table. One for actor `105` and 2nd time for actor `122`. If you use this approach your query will look something like this:

```
select f.* from film f INNER JOIN film_actor fa105 ON f.film_id = fa105.film_id and fa105.actor_id = 105
INNER JOIN film_actor fa122 ON f.film_id = fa122.film_id and fa122.actor_id = 122 ORDER by f.title
```

Another approach would be to write a nested query, but this above approach is cleaner for me.